# How do I use $(this) to reuse a particular selector in the condition

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, this

How do I use `$(this)` to reuse a particular instance of the `$('select').data('field')`  only if it is equal to a particular value in the condition.

```
if ($('select').data('field') === "DriverDiscovery.AddStatus") {
    alert( $(this) );
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
$('select').each(function(){//for each select element
     if($(this).data('field') == "DriverDiscovery.AddStatus"){//if the condition is met
          alert($(this).text());//print its text
     }
})
```

Comment: This helped solve my implementation of this code, however I changed the " 'selected' " in the condition to "this"  because prior to that it would grab the text from ALL selects. Thanks.